# Como armazenar valores a cada interação durante a repetição de uma estrutura - Python

Tags: python, loop, selenium-webdriver

```
lista= ["2,55","3,4","3,83","5,1","6,8"]


for i in range(len(lista)):


    lista[i] = lista[i] 


    #PREEENCHER VALOR

    navegador.find_element_by_xpath('...').send_keys(lista[i])
    time.sleep(3)
    #obter valor #
    valor = navegador.find_element_by_xpath('...')
    valor = valor.text[:-3].replace(',', '.')
```

Gostaria de armazenar cada valor gerado para cada interação feita.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português, talvez queira fazer um Tour: pt.stackoverflow.com/tour ou dar uma olhada na Central de Ajuda: pt.stackoverflow.com/tour e verificar como efetuar perguntas de uma forma que sejam respondidas rapidamente, tente informar o que você já tentou e poste o seu código, dificilmente alguém fará o trabalho por você. Como você não tem uma ideia de como fazer o que está precisando, inicialmente é melhor fazer uma pesquisa e depois se tiver alguma dificuldade na programação pode voltar a perguntar aqui.

Answer (score -1):

Se eu entendi bem a pergunta, você deve criar uma nova lista para armazenar os valores gerados.
Crie uma nova variável de valor lista vazia.

Exemplo:

```
valores = []
...
valor = valor.text[:-3].replace(',', '.')
valores.append(valor)
```

Infelizmente, não consigo entender seu código exatamente, as variáveis não estão no escopo desse código, não sei de onde vem `usinas`, por exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta
Na vdd esse usinas foi um erro na hora de passar o codico para aqui mas já editei